# SVN best practice - Deleting completed branches

Tags: svn, branch

Once you have finished/reintegrated a branch, is it best practice to delete the branch so your head branches folder only shows current branches?

If so, what would be a suitable time to delete reintegrated branches? After a minor release (which is when we tag).

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102472/subversion-branch-reintegration), it is recommended to delete your reintegrated branch immediately after reintegration and create a new one with the same (or different) name instead.