# SVN 1.8 best practice - Deleting completed branches

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

All, is it still recommended to delete completed branches in subversion 1.8? The [previous SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528464/svn-best-practice-deleting-completed-branches) refer to version 1.7. In 1.8 there's no *--reintegrate* anymore.

Comment: The link in the accepted answer explicitly refers to being able to do further work in the branch. Is that the situation you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no option *--reintegrate* anymore in 1.8 it is still called *reintegrating a branch*.

The SVN book nigthly version for 1.8 [states](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) (bold by me):

> Now that your private branch is merged to trunk, **you may wish to remove it** from the repository [svn delete on branch]. **If you choose not to delete** your branch after reintegrating it to the trunk **you may continue to perform sync merges from the trunk and then reintegrate the branch again**. If you do this, only the changes made on your branch after the first reintegrate are merged to the trunk.

Comment: So it's possible to reintegrate the branch multiple times to trunk without doing any record merges in between?

Comment: As it says you need to sync your branch. As far as I understand to prevent big merge conflicts on the reintegration merge. Record-only merges wouldn't be helpful, I think ...