# SVN merge an already merged branch to trunk

Tags: svn, merge

Using a command line version of SVN (SlikSvn), I have a branch Ive been working on for a while, and merged it into trunk as I thought I had finished with that branch.

But now, Ive done more work on the branch, and committed a number of new revisions (to the branch).
The trunk has not had any modifications since the branch was merged.

What I want to do now, is get my recent branch changes into trunk, and Im unsure if I should merge from the revision number where this branch started again, or from the revision where I last merged, or the one after... or maybe something else.

Very many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go into trunk working copy do

```
   svn merge URL/branchname
```

that's it.

Or in TortoiseSVN default merge revision range.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didnt know you could merge branches that easily, Ive been doing it using revision numbers all the time. Good work.

Comment: Starting with SVN Version 1.5 you can do that in that simple manner. This is called Merge-Tracking.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use `merge --reintegrate` when merging to trunk? That's the right way to do it. If so, you can continue working in the branch. But you need to block the merge from being re-merged into your branch. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102472/subversion-branch-reintegration/2330325#2330325).

Comment: No I didnt, I remember reading something somewhere that using --reintegrate can have some undesirable effect, but I cant remember what the undesirable effect was now... maybe it was the re-mergeing you mention, that what I read, was talking about. Thanks for the reply though and the link was very useful.