# SVN: development in a branch after re-integration

Tags: svn

I've made the mistake ([as indicated in the documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html)) of continuing to develop in a branch that has already been merged into the trunk.  What is the best way to preserve the work that I have done for another merge to the trunk?

Answer (score 0):

Check this prior question [Reintegrate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102472/subversion-branch-reintegration) and the referenced collabnet blog entry [here](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2008/07/subversion-merg/).

The short answer:  you're probably fine.

My recommendation would be to reintegrate/merge again and discard the branch.  Alternatively, checkout a new copy and copy over your changes you want to preserve.  You ought to be able to locate them in your working copy using 'svn st --recursive'.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a new branch from the trunk from a revision after the re-integration.  I then merged from the old branch to the new branch to grab the changes made post-re-integration.  These merged into the trunk without the conflict complaints encountered when attempting to merge again to the trunk from the already re-integrated branch.